# Load a specific file/CSS only in a certain page

Tags: templating, css

I want to load a .css file **only** in a certain page.

What's the magic code I need?

Answer (score 3):

You can register your file with Twig at the place you need it

```
{% do craft.app.getView().registerCssFile(alias('@assetUrl') ~ '/path/to/css') %}
```

Comment: yo there isn't something like {if this page} and then print the tag? I believe that's easier.

Comment: @dawn Robin's answer is perfectly valid, and is exactly the right answer for many scenarios. If you'd like other options, please expand on your original question.

Comment: You can wrap it around an `{% if %}` condition if you want, but usually you want to register the file where you need it. So when you include a template that requires your css file you'll register it. You can execute the line as many times as you want, Craft won't mess around and only insert the `style` tag once in your header

Answer (score 3):

You can check a specific URL segment. For example if you need to load some CSS on the About page and that URL is yoursite.com/about you can do this:

```
{% if craft.app.request.segments|first == 'about' %}
    {# Load CSS #}
{% endif %}
```

You could also check by `entry.id`

```
{% if entry is defined and entry.id == '123' %}
    {# Load CSS #}
{% endif %}
```

Replace "123" with the `id` of the entry you'd like to load the CSS for.

Comment: Good answer. But the second one will throw an error if you're on a page where `entry` does not exist.

Comment: Good point. I added a check for the entry being defined.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to use the [Parent function of Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/parent.html).

For this u have to define a block in your base template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ rev('/assets/dist/css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/lrj4mhv.css">
{% endblock %}
```

then in your page template (wich extends the base template) u just use it like this:

```
{% extends "_private/layout" %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {#here u can inject any css file u want to#}
{% endblock %}
```